# Installed Spyder. Where is pip?

Tags: python, pip, spyder

I'm trying to migrate away from Anaconda. I uninstalled Anaconda, then installed Spyder using the Windows standalone installer (executable). Now I need to add some packages.

Problem: `pip` is not on my Windows path. I also searched Spyder's installation directory for `pip.exe`, and couldn't find it. Please help! I see a lot of discussion of installing Spyder using `pip`, not installing `pip` using Spyder.

Comment: Spyder is just an IDE. It does not include Python or any Python tools. You still have to install Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command to check whether pip is installed:

py -m pip --version

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: Thanks. Although you didn't mention it, that page also has installation instructions (which are surprisingly difficult). I now have a working copy of `pip`.